# query for rows in table A that don't match rows in table B

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables :

[image: http://imageshack.us/f/854/7jpd.png/]

I need "clientes.id_cliente, clientes.nombre, clientes.apellido, clientes.empresa, clientes.correo" from first table but deleting the persons that appears in the second table (people who contract)

I tried this (among many other things):

```
SELECT clientes.id_cliente, clientes.nombre, clientes.apellido, clientes.empresa, clientes.correo
FROM clientes
INNER JOIN contratos_clientes
ON clientes.id_cliente != contratos_clientes.id_cliente
```

and this is the result:

[image]

I have tried different ways, but I've gotten nothing.

Comment: rather than changing the title to "[SOLVED]", you should just accept one of the answers. That marks it as solved, plus gives you and the answerer SO points.

Comment: Ok, perfect, solved.
Thank you very much to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, this is a `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` -- but that may not optimize well. If the queries that @a_horse_with_no_name posted don't perform well, you can also do:

```
SELECT clientes.id_cliente, clientes.nombre, clientes.apellido,
        clientes.empresa, clientes.correo
FROM clientes
LEFT JOIN contratos_clientes
ON clientes.id_cliente = contratos_clientes.id_cliente
WHERE contratos_clientes.id_cliente IS NULL
```

A `LEFT JOIN` asks for all rows from the left table (`clientes` table here), joined to corresponding rows (as defined by `ON`) in the right table (`contratos_clientes`) *if they exist*. For each row on the left, if the values don't exist for a given row, then all of the values in the right table's part of the row will be `NULL`. In your case, those are the rows you want -- so just check if a value on that right side is `NULL`. It's best to use a value that can't be `NULL` on its own, such as a PK field.

Incidentally, this sort of query -- "rows in A that don't match rows in B" -- is called an anti-join.

(Note: Usually when you just want the left part of a JOIN, you need to use `SELECT DISTINCT` so that it'll remove duplicates if a given row on the left matches multiple rows on the right. But in this case, you're only looking for `NULL` rows on the right, and at most one such "dummy" row is inserted per row on the left, so you can't have duplicates and thus don't need the `DISTINCT`.)

Comment: pending +1 for the anti-join answer, since this is probably the most likely query to perform well in MySQL; however, your `==` in the `ON` does not look like a valid MySQL [comparison operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html) and the `DISTINCT` is likely to cause unnecessary overhead since it looks like the PK is in the query and the optimizer might still spend time de-duping a set that can't possibly have duplicates.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Good call on both, thanks for those suggestions. I fixed the operator and explained why `DISTINCT` is not necessary, despite sometimes being necessary in similar joins.

Comment: Is MySQL really also bad at optimizing `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I actually wasn't sure, to be honest. I just checked (on a similar db, with real data in it) and they both EXPLAIN'ed to roughly the same plan. Yours had a subquery (it wasn't optimized out), while mine was optimized like a standard join. I don't know if the subquery has overhead associated with re-opening each subquery execution (per row on the left).

Comment: I just tried them out on a smallish data set, and they do seem roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You want a `NOT EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT clientes.id_cliente, 
       clientes.nombre, 
       clientes.apellido, 
       clientes.empresa, 
       clientes.correo
FROM clientes
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                  from contratos_clientes
                  where clientes.id_cliente = contratos_clientes.id_cliente);
```

Another option would be `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT clientes.id_cliente, 
       clientes.nombre, 
       clientes.apellido, 
       clientes.empresa, 
       clientes.correo
FROM clientes
WHERE clientes.id_cliente NOT IN (select contratos_clientes.id_cliente 
                                  from contratos_clientes
                                  where contratos_clientes.id_cliente IS NOT NULL);
```

The `IS NOT NULL` in the sub-query is necessary because the `NOT IN` operator will fail if a NULL value is returned for the `contratos_clientes.id_cliente` column. If that column is defined as `NOT NULL` that condition can be removed.

MySQL is known to be terribly bad at NOT IN statements, so the first one will probably perform better.